# Redirect to next parameter in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, redirect, loginview

I have an input field `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />`, but it wont replace `{{ next }}` with the value of the GET parameter. I can't find how to replace the value.

My view

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    template_name = 'user/login.html'

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        login(self.request, form.get_user())
            return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.success_url:
            redirect_to = self.success_url
        else:
            redirect_to = self.request.REQUEST.get(self.redirect_field_name, '')

        if not redirect_to:
            redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

        return redirect_to
```

Comment: what is your view code?

Comment: shouldn't `self.request.REQUEST.get('next')` be `self.request.GET.get('next')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override method `get_context_data` on class `LoginView`.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['next'] = self.request.REQUEST.get('next')
    return context
```

This assumes that the `GET` parameter will have the next url where user should be redirected in param `next`. So, request should be of form `localhost.com/login?next=/accounts/`